# What is the difference between char::is_digit and char::is_numeric?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, rust

What is the difference between `char::is_digit` and `char::is_numeric`?

I notice that a general numeric character gives an invalid digit error when converting to a number; is it possible to get the numeric value of a numeric character? Is that a valid thing to do?

Answer (score 3):

`char::is_numeric` checks whether a character is numeric [according to Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode) (specifically if it falls under Unicode General Categories Nd, Nl and No) while `char::is_digit` can recognize regular digits and digits in radixes different than 10 (up to 36), e.g. hexadecimal `a`-`f` (radix 16).

Example difference:

```
assert!(char::is_numeric('a')); // fails
assert!(char::is_digit('a', 10)); // fails
assert!(char::is_digit('a', 16)); // works
```

It's ok to obtain numeric values of characters - you just need to provide the right radix:

```
println!("{}", 'a'.to_digit(16).unwrap()); // 10
println!("{}", 'z'.to_digit(36).unwrap()); // 35
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_digit), 'digit' is defined to be only the following characters: `0-9` `a-z` `A-Z`.

The [`is_numeric`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_numeric) function looks to just check to see if the value is in fact a number there are some cool examples in the docs.